# Paymill: how to get list of client's credit cards, previously used in payments

Tags: .net, paymill

how to obtain a list of credit cards, (I guess, only last 4 digits) to show in a list to client? Could you advise me with a flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PAYMILL the credit card representation is the [Payment object](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/#document-payments). When you [create](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/#create-new-transaction-with) a transaction with a token, the API will always generate it, and it will be returned to you in the "payment" field. You also have the option to explicitly [create](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/#create-new-credit-card-payment-with) a payment object from a token, without creating the transaction. If you do so, consider [this limitation](https://paymill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200261507) that comes with the 3DS flow.

You can keep track of payment objects in your database, but you can also use the PAYMILL API. For each of your customers, create a corresponding [client](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/#document-clients) object. When you create a transaction or a payment, send the client id along. A similar flow can be seen in the [iOS tutorial](https://github.com/paymill/paymill-example-ios-parse-honeystore#architecture).

You can accomplish all above with the .net wrapper. Please make sure you always use the latest version and you are using the official wrapper: https://github.com/paymill/paymill-net